# Need to show union data properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to against to patient selected data in this table and another table all show it but there is all patient data is show with `IsKeyAttrIsChecked` flag

Query:-

```
 select 
    a.KeyAttribute,
    a.PatKeyAttId,
    b.IsKeyAttrIsChecked,
    b.PatientUserId
from PatientKeyAttributeMaster a 
    Left join PatientKeyAttributeMap b 
        on (a.PatKeyAttId = b.PatKeyAttributeId)
UNION 
select 
    keyAttribute,
    PatKeyAttId,
    IsKeyAttrIsChecked,
    PatientUserId
from 
    (
        select 
            a.KeyAttribute,
            a.PatKeyAttId,
            b.IsKeyAttrIsChecked,
            b.PatientUserId
        from PatientKeyAttributeMaster a 
            inner join PatientKeyAttributeMap b 
                on (a.PatKeyAttId = b.PatKeyAttributeId)
        where b.PatientUserId = 176845 or b.IsKeyAttrIsChecked=1
    ) as a 
group by keyAttribute,PatKeyAttId,IsKeyAttrIsChecked,PatientUserId
```

output:-

```
   KeyAttribute             |   PatKeyAttId |IsKeyAttrIsChecked|PatientUserId
Anxiety                         4041            NULL            NULL
Drop in work performance        4039            1               177849
Drowsiness                      4032            NULL            NULL
Excess weight gain              4036            NULL            NULL
Irritability                    4040            1               171834
 Anger at work                  4040            1               177847
Anger at work                   4040            1               177849
Persistent backache             4034            1               171834
Persistent cough                4035            1               176845
```

Expected output:-

```
KeyAttribute            |   PatKeyAttId |IsKeyAttrIsChecked|PatientUserId
Anxiety                         4041            NULL            NULL
Drop in work performance        4039            0               NULL
Drowsiness                      4032            NULL            NULL
Excess weight gain              4036            NULL            NULL
Persistent cough                4035            1               176845
Irritability                    4040            0               NULL
 Anger at work                  4040            0               NULL
Anger at work                   4040            0               NULL
Persistent backache             4034            0               NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to answer this one I'm afraid. What do the individual statements return? Are they giving you the right rows?

Comment: We don't have any original data to work with here. Why for example, does `Anger at work` have `NULL` as a value in your expected output? Why are the values `177847` and `177849` not applicable, as they are clearly being returned by your dataset. Here's a good place to start: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/ Also, please align your columns, your data is **very** difficult to read like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And, one of my biggest pet peeves: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). This is especially bad in your query, where `a` can be `PatientKeyAttributeMaster` in first or second subquery, or `a` could be the whole dataset returned in the first subquery. `b` is just as bad. I really suggest looking into how to use suitable aliases.

Comment: @Larnu no sir this data is dumy data just for example and this all above values in one column.

Comment: Then supply us with "dummy" sample data we can run your query against.

Comment: @DipGirase You still haven't given us what your *source* data looks like so this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a, b, c, d, e etc. as table aliases. Not keen on reusing `a` again for the subquery though. I like `z`.

Answer (score 1):

this ans in above post

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT PatientUserId FROM PatientKeyAttributeMap WHERE PatientUserId = 177848)
        Begin


            DECLARE @TEMPDATA TABLE 
            (
             PatKeyAttId int
            ,KeyAttribute nvarchar(max)
            ,IsKeyAttrIsChecked bit 
            ,PatientUserId int
            ,KeyAttributeCategory nvarchar(800)
            )

            --select * from @TEMPDATA
            insert into @TEMPDATA ( PatKeyAttId ,KeyAttribute ,IsKeyAttrIsChecked ,PatientUserId ,KeyAttributeCategory)
            select a.PatKeyAttId,  a.KeyAttribute,0 as IsKeyAttrIsChecked,177848,b.KeyAttrCategory
            from PatientKeyAttributeMaster a 
            inner join KeyAttributeCategory b on (a.KeyAttributeCategoryId = b.KeyAttributeCategoryId ) 

            update a 
            set a.IsKeyAttrIsChecked = 1
            from @TEMPDATA a 
            where a.PatKeyAttId in (
            select PatKeyAttributeId from PatientKeyAttributeMap where PatientUserId = 177848 and  IsKeyAttrIsChecked = 1
            )
            --select * from @TEMPDATA


             WITH List AS(
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PatKeyAttId)  as RowNumber,
            PatKeyAttId 
            ,KeyAttribute 
            ,IsKeyAttrIsChecked 
            ,PatientUserId
            ,KeyAttributeCategory
             from @TEMPDATA
             )

            select a.* ,b.TotalRecords as TotalRecords 
            from List a
            LEFT JOIN (
                Select max(RowNumber) TotalRecords from  List 
            ) b on (1 = 1)
    End
```